# CSS does not import.

Tags: html, css

Why isn't my style.css making changes to index.html?
Both files validate perfectly.
 Folder set up: site > index.html, style.css.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>new site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

        <header>
            <div id="status">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/status.png" alt="Currently available for work" /></a>
            </div><!-- end status -->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h1><a href="#"><img src="img/banner.png" alt="Return to the homepage" /></a></h1>
            <div id="blurb">
                <p>blah blah blah lorem ipsum blah blah</p>
            </div><!-- end blurb -->
        </header>

        <div class="services">
            <ul>
                <li><h2>Design 1</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
                <li><h2>Design 2</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
                <li><h2>Design 3</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
                <li><h2>Design 4</h2><p>Nulla et diam risus. Praesent vestibulum augue non purus tincidunt placerat. Sed in orci leo. Duis dignissim nibh vitae lacus placerat et posuere</p></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end services -->

        <div class="recent">
            <div id="recent-work">

            </div><!-- end recent-work -->
            <div id="recent-blog">

            </div><!-- end recent-blog -->
        </div><!-- end recent -->



    </div><!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
/* Reset */

html, body, div, span, object, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, address, code, img,
small, strong, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li
fieldset, form, label {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
    background: url(img/background.png) repeat;
    font-family: alexandriaflf-bold-webfont, 
                 Constantia,
                 "Lucida Bright",
                 "Bitstream Vera Serif",
                 "Liberation Serif",
                 serif;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

/* Type */

@font-face {
    font-family: alexandriaflf-bold-webfont;
    src: url('type/alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('type/alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('type/alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('type/alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('type/alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.svg#') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: alexandriaflf-bolditalic-webfont;
    src: url('type/alexandriaflf-bolditalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('type/alexandriaflf-bolditalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('type/alexandriaflf-bolditalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('type/alexandriaflf-bolditalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('type/alexandriaflf-bolditalic-webfont.svg#') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    src: url('type/nevis-webfont.eot');
    src: url('type/nevis-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('type/nevis-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('type/nevis-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('type/nevis-webfont.svg#') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
    font-family: nevis-webfont;
    font-size: 160%;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: normal;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 80%;
    font-weight: bold;
}


p {
    font-size: 80%;
}

a {
    color: #202020;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: The markup looks correct (and works for me locally), if you're developing on a server (local or remote) you might have the path wrong for `href="style.css"`.

Comment: if your browser have developer tools, open it up. there should be a log for requesting style.css and the resulting response.

Comment: The CSS is pretty bland: http://jsfiddle.net/A3D8r/ Are you sure it isn't working? If you add something immediately visual, for example `* { color:red; }`, does that not show either?

Comment: @LeleDumbo Firebug gives me this: "This element has no style rules. You can create a rule for it."

Comment: @Juhana body { background: red; } makes no changes.

Comment: I'm developing through Coda, if that helps. My file set up is exactly how @artlung has listed above.. I don't think the style.css path is wrong, but what would you recommend given the files listed above?

Comment: I don't know anything about Coda, but you'll definitely want to confirm that style.css is being loaded. Perhaps see in the Net tab in Firebug if the resource is loaded successfully, and if not then determine the syntax that your framework requires to load a file from the root of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your markup and CSS, the folder you're developing in should have these folders and files in them. Does it?

```
index.html
style.css
js/
    scripts.js
img/
    status.png
    banner.png
    background.png
type/
    alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.eot
    alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.woff
    alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.ttf
    alexandriaflf-bold-webfont.svg
```

If your stylesheet is not being applied, it's either that you called it incorrectly (no, your link tag is fine) or the CSS syntax is bad (no, looks okay) or the file is not where you are declaring it should be (bad path). Rarer situations might be: you've disabled stylesheets and forgot to reenable; one or both of the files has some kind of encoding error or a stray bad character that makes it corrupt.

---

**EDIT**

I've arranged your index.html and style.css as you have described and this is what I see. The styles apply. In Chrome Developer Tools you'll see the `h2` is highlighted and the specified styles are applying. At the minimum, I would expect you to see this. If you don't see this, you have something either very wrong with your environment or you're not explaining the situation accurately.

[image: Screenshot of debugging this]

Comment: Nice to see when someone includes the rarer circumstances ;) Especially since if it's not a bad file path, those would seem to be the problem.

Comment: my root folder has all of those files, yes. sorry, i thought i listed them all out earlier. 
how do i check if stylesheets have been disabled? i'm using coda, if that helps. if there was an encoding error, would that not show during validation? both my html and css are 100% valid.

Comment: @AMC What result do you get if you load into a browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer). It sounds like you have an issue inside Coda, actually. There are a bunch of messages in the Coda Users list related to this: https://groups.google.com/group/coda-users/search?q=refresh+preview -- I wonder if some of the advice there would be helpful.

Comment: @artlung When shown in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari I get only the plain HTML- images are not even showing. I'll take a peek at the Coda group, thanks.

Comment: @AMC I don't know, I've attached it working for me on my Mac.

Comment: Ah, I wonder if you're editing in some kind of WYSIWYG mode? If you're seeing HTML on the page, then you've pasted in the code not as code, but as content. That may be the culprit.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I'm not in WYSIWYG.. I've not touched the Coda settings at all, nor do I think it has WYSIWYG.
When in the browser, I see the bullet points by the UL and the links are blue with an underline(all default). What should I look for in the environment to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: @AMC I would shut down Coda entirely and instead start over with something like Textwrangler or Sublime Text 2 or TextMate. A simple text editor and start over from scratch.